# json_encode() function adds backslash

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a PHP Array with the word `'s morgens` in it. I'm using a function which escapes the single quote, `json_encode()` adds another backslash to it which causes an error in the SQL code. The parameter `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` causes the following error:

> Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

The output is as follows, before json_encode():

```
string(11) "\'s middags"
```

And after json_encode():

```
"\\'s middags"
```

Its equivalent (long, 64) won't work, it doesn't throw an error. How can I prevent `json_encode()` from adding a backslash?

(Sorry for bad English, it's not my native language)

Comment: You seem to have an XY problem. Instead of trying to change the specific format of the JSON, change the code which generates the SQL so it can handle special characters. This probably just means using bound arguments instead of string concatenation. Better still, don't shove JSON into a relational database - store the separate bits of data in different rows/columns/tables in a sensible normalised form that you can properly query with SQL.

Comment: That aside, your question is on the road to be closed anyway. You haven't provided a clear problem statement (you said "The parameter JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES causes an error" — WHAT error?) nor have you provided a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

> json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

This means that the constant `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` is not defined (it should be `64`) and is being implicitly treated as the string `"JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES"`.

This means you are using a version of PHP **too old** to support `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`.

PHP has supported `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` since version 5.4.0.

The 5.4 branch went end of life in 2015. It has been over three years since it received a security update. You are using a version **older** than that (i.e. one that has been unsupported for **at least** 4 years and 2 months).

This means your server has serious security holes.

The solution: **Upgrade to a supported version of PHP**.

The better solution: **Upgrade to a supported version of PHP** and also take the advice given in my earlier comment:

> Instead of trying to change the specific format of the JSON, change the code which generates the SQL so it can handle special characters. This probably just means using bound arguments instead of string concatenation. Better still, don't shove JSON into a relational database - store the separate bits of data in different rows/columns/tables in a sensible normalised form that you can properly query with SQL.

Comment: In that case PHP should print a NOTICE. If the OP doesn't see it, he should turn on error-reporting in the first place. And then it appears to be an XY problem as you wrote yourself...

Answer (score 0):

You confusing different things here.

1. Your original string, `'s morgens`, should be inserted to database using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). With prepared statements, you have no reason to escape quotes for database operations. If you want to escape them anyway, then you'd do it directly before running the SQL statement. You usually don't `json_encode()` your escaped string, although it's possible and shouldn't raise problems.
2. When you encode your string with `json_encode()`, you of course have to decode it with `json_decode()` later on. If you do that, there wouldn't be two backslashes in your string.
3. `json_encode()` takes an integer as second argument. You apparently wrote something like `json_encode($str, "JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES")`, but it had to be `json_encode($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`. But as mentioned, this argument is usually *not* required when (1) and (2) are taken into consideration.

So I guess the first thing for you to do is to clean up:

- Insert to database: Use prepared statements (or escape the query values).
- Transmit data: `json_encode()`
- Receive data: `json_decode()`.